# How to dynamically pass column name while framing the case statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, case, concatenation

I'm writing a query in MySQL wherein, i'm framing a case statement to get some values. However, i'm not getting any way to pass the column name dynamically in the 'then' statement of the case clause. Below is the code am trying.

```
    SELECT CONCAT (COLUMN_NAME,(CASE WHEN 
                     IS_NULL_FLAG = 'Y' AND COLUMN_TYPE = 'NUMBER' then '==  ?  (int ?) null:Convert.ToInt32(@COLUMN_NAME) AS @COLUMN_NAME'
                     else ''
                     end 
                    ) )FROM SCHEMA_REF WHERE SCHEMA_REF.ENTITY_NAME = 'CUSTOMERS1_REP'  ORDER BY SCHEMA_ID;
```

Here while fetching the record, i'm trying to get the column name, but it is not getting passed.
Any idea on how can I pass the column name dynamically in the 'then' clause of the case statement.

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Agreed. But how do I get a workaround for this now?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is, select a set of columns and based on some other column value, I need to concat a few keywords to the selected columns. I'm not sure if there is any other way around to achieve this apart from CASE statement. That's why this approach came up.